# Save data from API response to re-use it

Tags: cypress

I try to use Cypress to test my application. In this application I have a form, submitting it causes a POST API call. The API response contains the ID of the created resource. I would like to save this ID into a variable to reuse it later in my test (to clean the resource at the end of the test).

This is my Cypress code

```js
describe('Templates', function() {

  let templateID = null

  before('before once', function() {
      cy.server();
      // define a route with alias for my POST requesst
      cy.route({method: 'POST', url:'/api/templates/'}).as('api_template_create')
      cy.visit('');
  });

  it('Create a new template', function() {
    cy.get('.my-form #type').select('book')
    cy.get('.my-form #title').type('Cyress title test')
    ...
    cy.get('.my-form input:submit').click()
    cy.wait('@api_template_create').then(xhr => {
      const response = xhr.response.body
      templateID = response.metadata.pid
      cy.log(templateID) // at this time 'templateID' contains the correct value
    })
    cy.wait(2000)
    cy.log(templateID) // templateID is null (as initial value)

    // continue test....
    // ...at the end call the DELETE API with templateID as param
  });
});
```

See below the result of this code:

[image: cypress test result]

L#23 is the log into the wait().then() --> correct one 
L#25 is the log after in the main 'it' test --> return to null (as initial value)

Is it a way to solve my problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can write the id into a fixture file and then re-use it throughout your tests. You can look into the [Cypress Fixtures Docs](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/fixture.html#Syntax).

```
describe('Templates', function () {

    let templateID = null

    before('before once', function () {
        cy.server();
        // define a route with alias for my POST requesst
        cy.route({ method: 'POST', url: '/api/templates/' }).as('api_template_create')
        cy.visit('');
    });

    it('Create a new template', function () {
        cy.get('.my-form #type').select('book')
        cy.get('.my-form #title').type('Cyress title test')
        //...
        cy.get('.my-form input:submit').click()
        cy.wait('@api_template_create').then(xhr => {
            const response = xhr.response.body
            templateID = response.metadata.pid
            cy.log(templateID)

            //Write the id into a fixtures file
            cy.writeFile('cypress/fixtures/testdata.json', { id: templateID })
        }).then(function () {
            cy.wait(2000)

            //Access Value from Fixtures file
            cy.fixture('cypress/fixtures/testdata.json').then(function (testdata) {
                cy.log(this.testdata.id)
            })
        })
    })
})
```